# How to add values from checkbox to array?

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, checkbox

I need your help.

I'm working on a jsp application.

The thing is that I have a form within a "select-option" then depending on the item I select from the "select option" I get a list with checkboxes, and I can get the checkboxes values in my servlet, but now what I try to do is to get does values and add them to an array. How can I do that?

JSP code:

```
 //Select-option
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td width="50%" style="text-align: left;">                    
       <select class="selectSmall" id="a_selectCta" name="a_selectCta" 
             style="margin-bottom: 5px; width: 310px;">
        <option value="">Seleccione un Cuentahabiente</option>          
         <%
          for (Ctahabiente habiente : CtahabienteDAO.getCtahabientes()) {
         if (ctahabiente != null && habiente.getIdCtahabiente().equalsIgnoreCase(ctahabiente.getIdCtahabiente())) {
          %>
        <option selected="selected" value="<%=ctahabiente.getIdCtahabiente()%>">&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <%=ctahabiente.getIdCtahabiente() + " - " + ctahabiente.getDesCtahabiente()%></option>
        <%
        } else {
        %>                                  
        <option value="<%=habiente.getIdCtahabiente()%>">&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <%=habiente.getIdCtahabiente() + " - " + habiente.getDesCtahabiente()%></option>
        <%                                          }                                       }
        %>
        </select>
       </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    //List with checkboxes from select-option
    <%
     if (request.getAttribute("a_accion") != null) {
    %>
    <%
     ctahabiente = null;                                 
     List<Directorio> listaDirectorio = (List<Directorio>)request.getAttribute("a_listaDirectorio");
     ctahabiente =(Ctahabiente)request.getAttribute("a_ctahabiente");
    %>
    <table class="tableDirectorio" style="text-align: left;">   
     <tr>
      <th width="5px">CheckBox</th>
      <th width="5px">ID dir</th>
      <th width="5px">ID cta</th>
    </tr>
    <%
     if(listaDirectorio.size()>0){                          
       itDirectorio = listaDirectorio.iterator();                   
       boolean renglon=true; // renglon par
     while(itDirectorio.hasNext()){
      directorio = (Directorio) itDirectorio.next();
      if(renglon){                          
    %>  
    <tr>
     <td style="background-color: #fff; text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="checkCta" name="checkCta" value="<%=directorio.getIdDirectorio()%>" /></td>
     <td style="background-color: #fff; text-align: center;"><%=directorio.getIdDirectorio()!= 0? directorio.getIdDirectorio():""%></td>              
     <td style="background-color: #fff; text-align: center;"><%=directorio.getIdCtahabiente()!= null? directorio.getIdCtahabiente():""%></td>
    </tr>
    <%
    renglon=false;
     }else{                         
    %>
    <tr>
     <td style="background-color: #fff; text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="checkCta" name="checkCta" value="<%=directorio.getIdDirectorio()%>" /></td>
     <td style="background-color: #fff; text-align: center;"><%=directorio.getIdDirectorio()!= 0? directorio.getIdDirectorio():""%></td>    
     <td style="background-color: #fff; text-align: center;"><%=directorio.getIdCtahabiente()!= null? directorio.getIdCtahabiente():""%></td>
    </tr>
    <%
    renglon=true;   
     }
    }
    %>
   </table>
    <%}%>
```

Comment: How do you read formatting like that? If I can see correctly, you are even missing a `}`. The indentation even after Romani edited it just makes it so difficult to actually find out what it does. What editor do you use? Eclipse? How about something like this: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=2yu60rP9 and if you don't want tabs replace them with spaces. Feedback plz.

Comment: Also, what does the renglon toggle do? The if and else are the same! Also, class+CSS > style="". Also width="5" - no px.